# How to get com.sun.opengl.util.j2d

Tags: java, opengl

I am trying to compile a java code which has the following line:

**import com.sun.opengl.util.j2d.TextRenderer;**

The compiler throws the following error:

**cotSpectral.java:29: error: package com.sun.opengl.util.j2d does not exist**

What is the problem? Do I have to install some .jar files or do I have to tell the compiler where to find some standard libraries or is it something else? I couldn't find anything on google. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download jar file and import to your IDE, or add dependency to it if you use something like Maven/Gradle etc.

Probably you are looking for [it](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jogl/jogl)

Comment: This is it! Thanks a lot! I upvoted your answer, however, it is not visible since I do not have enough reputation.

Comment: Np. I think you could mark it as an answer with any reputation, to close this question.